# Executable not found although in PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

My $PATH is set to a lot of directories including `~/bin` and `~/target/bin`

I want to execute script.sh which is in `~/target/bin` but I get the error `bash: ~/bin/script.sh: No such file or directory`

This confuses me since `which` finds the correct directory ~/target/bin and ~/target/bin/script.sh executes fine.

Are there any special settings in bash that could lead to this wrong path handling?

Comment: Please post command line and PATH content. You might have better luck asking on Superuser.

Comment: Does the script have execute permission?

Comment: @Barmar yes it has. As mentioned the script executes with full path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try running `hash -r` to clear the executable cache.

Bash saves the location of the executable in a cache so it doesn't have to search the entire path again if you re-run the command.  [More on the `hash` command](http://ss64.com/bash/hash.html)

Comment: that has helped; thank you very much. Could you please explain what this executable cache is? I've never heard of it before

Comment: `rehash` in csh/tcsh